# Who is responsible for locking the bootloader?

Tags: bootloader, lg

I was wondering who is in charge of the locking of bootloaders.

I recently chatted with a representative from LG-UK enquiring about the unlocking of bootloaders. I was told that I need to speak to Google about why the bootloader is locked. I suspect this information to be false but just to be sure I wanted to ask on here if anyone knows who is actually responsible for the locking of bootloaders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the LG rep was just trying to get rid of you. Bootloader locking is an important security feature. It prevents a thief getting past the lockscreen by just flashing a custom ROM to circumvent the PIN or password. It's a core part of Android but the phone manufacturer has to make it work by signing their system images with their private key and storing the public key in the phone's bootloader.

Answer (score 1):

The OEMs (Original Equipment Manufacturer) or Carriers like verizon, AT&T, etc Lock Bootloaders, Google Devices Like Pixel come with unlockable bootloaders via Fastboot.